# Cypress how to check if the values in the table is in ascending order or descending order

Tags: cucumber, cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I have the table which contains any values like names, addresses and dates etc.
Need to check if the values in the table should be in ascending or descending order after performing sorting option

1.Here how I can verify if the values in the table is in ascending or descending order
2.How I can use the two functions isAscending and isDescending
I have stored the each elements in the array by using the below code

```js
let Arr1 = new Array()
cy.get('selector')
  .each(($el) => {Arr1.push($el.text()) })
cy.log(Arr1)
```

For checking sorting order I have tried below code but it does not works

```js
cy.wrap(Arr1).should('equal', Arr1.sort()); 
// here if the array is in descending order also it's passing
```

```js
function isAscending(arr) {
  return arr.every(function (x, i) { 
    return i === 0 || x >= arr[i - 1];  
  })
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The `isAscending()` function can be applied in a `.should()` with `satisfy` matcher.

See [chaijs - satisfy](https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_satisfy)

> ```js
> expect(1).to.satisfy(function(num) {
>   return num > 0;
> })
> ```

For example the equivalent Cypress should expressions would be

```js
function isAscending(arr) {
  return arr.every(function (x, i) { 
    return i === 0 || x >= arr[i - 1];  
  }); 
}

let Arr1 = new Array()
cy.get('selector')
  .each(($el) => {Arr1.push($el.text()) })
  .then(() => {
    cy.wrap(Arr1).should('satisfy', isAscending)
  })
```

Comment: While using the 'satisfy' assertion it throws an error that in the isAscending function the every is not defined..should I need to install any dependencies

Answer (score 3):

You cannot test an array with `eq`, that is only for single values. You must use `deep.eq`.

The page:

```html
<ascending>
  <span>a</span>
  <span>b</span>
  <span>c</span>
</ascending>

<descending>
  <span>c</span>
  <span>b</span>
  <span>a</span>
</descending>
```

The test:

```js
it('ascending - passing', () => {
  let arr1 = new Array() 
  cy.get('ascending span')
    .each($el => arr1.push($el.text() ) 
    .then(() => {
      cy.log(arr1)
      cy.wrap(arr1).should('deep.equal', [...arr1].sort())
    })
})

it('descending - passing', () => {
  let arr2 = new Array() 
  cy.get('descending span')
    .each($el => arr2.push($el.text() )
    .then(() => {
      cy.log(arr2)
      cy.wrap(arr2).should('deep.equal', [...arr2].sort().reverse())
    })
})

it('descending - failing', () => {
  let arr3 = new Array() 
  cy.get('descending span')
    .each($el => arr3.push($el.text() ) 
    .then(() => {
      cy.log(arr3)
      cy.wrap(arr3).should('deep.equal', [...arr3].sort()) 
    })
})
```

The result:

**Cypress test log**

[[image: Cypress test log]]

Comment: This also not works for me.. tried the same using 'deep.equal' in the array I have the values like name, address and DOB .. where Every value is up to 15 characters and the array length upto 50 values

Comment: I have the values like
```<ascending>
  <span>auasy qw a</span>
  <span>bdhs ahsh</span>
  <span>cdbshh</span><span>2023-05-04 14:22</span>
</ascending>```

Comment: Try again with your particular selectors, you can see it works from my screenshot.

Answer (score 2):

Wait for the code to run before testing or logging the array.

Cypress does not immediately (synchronously) give you the result. In your code you have missed the asynchronous operator `.then()`.

```js
let Arr1 = new Array() 
cy.get('selector')
  .each(($el) => {Arr1.push($el.text()) }) 
  .then(() => {
    cy.log(Arr1)
    cy.wrap(Arr1).should('equal', Arr1.sort())
  })
```

Comment: This is the which I have tried and it doesn't fails if the array is in descending order